# Trending algorithm on Redis

Tags: redis

I am trying to build a trending algorithm on redis.

I have Actions which have Reactions. I need the Actions created in the last 36hours with most reactions.

I tried to create a Set and score each Action according to the # of reactions.

```
zadd myset 0 "action_1"
zadd myset 1 "action_2"
zadd myset 1 "action_3"
```

and then I can Zincrby that key each time i have a reaction.

I tried to expire the "action_1" key but it doesn´t remove the key from the set.

I also tried to have two sets, and in one of them use the unix timestamp as score. I can easily get the actions in the last 36hs but I don´t know how to intersect that with my original set.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!